# How to view HTTP POST/GET responses in a browser?

Tags: java, sockets, http, network-programming

I'm learning how to send HTTP requests in Java. Is there a way to visually see the POST/GET responses in a browser? UI and all? I know how to perform the requests in Java and receive html printed out in the console, but it would be easier for me to just see the website itself in the browser.

do i need a plugin? or do i need to open up a socket connection and do something with localhost?

Sorry if this question is a duplicate/is not clear: I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firefox, you can press Ctr+Shift+Q and click on Network. Once you visit a page, it will show you the request in the list area. If you click on a request, it will show you the request and response headers. Very useful for debugging sites. I hope that's what you were asking. BTW, I have Firefox 30.0 in Win 8.1. I don't know about previous versions.

EDIT: If you want to intercept the HTTP request generated from Java, you can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It may have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I use Firebug for firefox. It shows requests, responses, and all headers in real time (with measuring latency) so it's really convenient for development. It's add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to console.log the object and in most browsers click on the object in development mode, expand it, and see all of its properties.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome you can right click -> Inspect Element and go to the `Network` tab. Refreshing the page will begin tracking the page you are on. When you send out requests, the request log will record them.